# Trouble separating projects in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, sdl-2

I'm creating a game framework in C++ using SDL in Visual Studio (Community 2013). I started with a single project which contained both my game framework and some simple application code to test it out. Now, I have come to a point where I would like to separate the game code from the framework which it uses. I'd like to have two separate Visual Studio projects, one for the framework and one for the game.

However, when I try this, I cannot get the previously working code to link properly. I decided to keep the original project as the one for the framework, and moved the application code into the newly created project. As far as I can tell, I have set all the include directories, library directories and additional dependencies to match what the existing project has. I have also duplicated the necessary dlls to the new project, as it will be the starting project (which I have set as such).

The linker seems to be having trouble with functions that take SDL defined datatypes - for example, I have an Input class which handles game input in the framework. Although I have a function (which worked pre project split):

```
bool isKeyDown(const SDL_Keycode& keycode);
```

it appears in the linker error as

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall fj::Input::isKeyDown(int const &)" (?isKeyDown@Input@fj@@QAE_NABH@Z) referenced in function...
```

Notice how `SDL_Keycode` has become `int` for some reason, despite the fact `#include <SDL.h>` is present in the file with this function! Also, this function has gone unmoved in the project split, and is only being called from the new project. Can anyone diagnose what I've done wrong here, considering this error message data type change?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are linking to the exact same library(Careful not to mix Debug with Release).

In `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` make sure you include the correct .lib files

Make sure you are passing the same Preprocessor directives and that your Library Paths are set up correctly.

Just to clarify, if you run this

```
typedef int OtherInt;
void f(OtherInt m);

int main() {
     f(0);
}
```

the linker will complain with an `int` also.  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl f(int)" (?f@@YAXH@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: Ah, so the `int` in my linker error isn't indicative of any wrongdoing on my part?

As for the additional dependencies and library directories, both projects have the exact same string, and the preprocessor directives have been unchanged for both projects.

Comment: It seems that functions like `isKeyDown` are your callbacks and the linker can' t find these. Make sure that their definitions are provided in the current project or if they are in the other project, they are being exported properly and the linker can find them. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx)